# Is Orchard the right CMS for this project?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms

I'm just looking for some advice really on CMS choice. The website will need some kind of CMS for sure, because the requirement is that the end user is able to add multiple "project case studies" under a bunch of different categories, and also spawn separate pages, and change general bits of content around the site. It's quite simple really, but the site needs to be easily navigated where these case studies are loaded via AJAX requests.

I'm looking closely at Orchard, a .NET CMS based on MVC2, but it seems kinda like overkill for the project - it has a bunch of features I'd never be using on the website and I don't want to overdo it. Plus, it's still a little bit buggy because debug messages keep coming up looking for debug classes that don't exit.

Any advice would be awesome!

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you go through your old questions and mark answers as accepted. This way, more people are likely to answer this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5565086/is-orchard-or-umbraco-mvc/5567785#5567785) recently, regarding whether to use Umbraco or Orchard as a backend for ASP.NET webstie/application. You could try reading this, I guess you'd find a solution there.

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to opensource .net cms, I had very good experience with **N2 CMS**. You can check it out on GitHub: https://github.com/n2cms/n2cms

Comment: The N2 site linked there is off-line.

Answer (score 2):

No matter what CMS you choose, it's likely to have stuff you don't need, as a CMS is necessarily casting its net very wide. It is supposed, after all, to be able to manage any kind of content.
I'd like to understand what you mean by "debug messages keep coming up looking for debug classes that don't exist". Can you elaborate, maybe on a PM so I can understand if that is a real bug that we should fix.

Comment: We've decided not to use an out-of-the-box CMS and just do a bespoke one instead. It's just that we have a very narrow scope for this project so it makes sense. Thanks for your reply anyway :)